# Aplicación C# con base de datos: ¿web o escritorio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, aplicación-web

Quiero diseñar una aplicación en C# con base de datos. Consiste en leer los registros que me llegan en texto plano (txt), trocearlos en campos según normativa VDA, y guardar en diferentes tablas, en función del tipo de registro. No necesito guardar un histórico a largo plazo.

Con los datos guardados, hay que hacer ciertas operaciones para agrupar artículos y cantidades, y poder facturar luego. Posiblemente, más adelante la aplicación permitirá exportar esos datos en formato XML.

Me planteo si hacerlo en una aplicación de escritorio, portable, con algún tipo de motor de base de datos sencillo (SQL CE o SQLite), o si hacerlo como aplicación web, con acceso a un SQL Server Express. Sería para un entorno de empresa, donde dos o tres personas van a utilizar esta aplicación.

No he desarrollado antes una aplicación web, sí alguna sencilla de escritorio. Tampoco necesito que sea una interfaz muy vistosa, es para uso interno de la empresa.

Mis dudas son: ¿Es muy diferente la programación para web del escritorio? Aparte del tema de publicación en IIS, ¿debo tener en cuenta algún otro tipo de complicación (no incluyo usuarios ni login, que de momento no es necesario)? Y sin querer originar un "flame": ¿cuáles serían los criterios para decantarse por web o por escritorio?

Si este no es el foro adecuado para preguntar, agradecería que me orientéis dónde buscar info...

Muchas gracias.

Javier.

Comment: En realidad,no es el foro adecuado para preguntarlo. Pero te doy mi opinión. En un entorno reducido y con tan pocos usuarios, yo te aconsejaría hacer una aplicación de escritorio..

Comment: Hola Javier. Es demasiado amplia y las respuestas posibles son muy variadas... Te aconsejo que hagas una pregunta especifica y intentes reducir la cantidad de explicación. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La programación web y la de escritorio son diferentes. Así se utilice el mismo lenguaje.
Si lo hace como aplicación de escritorio y luego decide migrarlo solo podría aprovechar para adaptar el código de la lógica.

He visto que algunos hacen sus programas para ejecutarlos como locales usando web ya que en el sistema operativo puede correr el entorno que ejecutaría en un servidor.

Por lo que describe quizás la mejor opción si es hacer una aplicación de escritorio. Probablemente resulte menos compleja y mas ligera debido a los requerimientos que describe.

Comment: Fpme, buenas. Tal y como está, la pregunta será cerrada por Opinion Peronal. No se deberian contestar a preguntas que no cumplen los criterios establecidos en el Centro de Ayuda. Un saludo

Comment: Ya sé que la pregunta es amplia, y es de opinión, pero bueno, es lo que buscaba, una opinión. De todas formas, gracias a Fpme y a Pikoh porque me han dado una orientación.  
Cierro la pregunta.